# Count equal elements in two lists in python

Tags: python, list, count

I want to take two lists and want to count the values that appear in both but considering **the same position**.

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = [4, 5, 3, 6, 5]

returnMatches(a, b)
```

would return `2`, for instance.

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = [1, 2, 3, 3, 5]

returnMatches(a, b)
```

would return `4`, for instance.

Is there a pythonic one line option or do I really need to iterate over both lists?

Thanks

Comment: Are you familiar with [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip)?

Comment: Found the way, you mean. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try

```py
output = sum([x == y for x, y in zip(a, b)])
```

I am not sure if it needs further clarification. You might want to look into "list comprehension" and `zip()` if you are not familiar with them.

Answer (score 2):

Look up what [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) is and how [list comprehension and generator expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#generator-expressions-and-list-comprehensions) work:

```
def count_matches(a, b):
  return sum(x == y for x, y in zip(a, b))
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
returnMatches = lambda a,b:sum([x==y for x,y in zip(a,b)]
```

This is the same as:

```py
def returnMatches(a, b):
    matches = 0
    for x, y in zip(a, b):
        matches += 1
    return matches
```

Take a look at `zip()` for more information on that builtin